# Where to get pre-labeled news articles to proceed clustering algorithm

Tags: text, nlp, cluster-analysis

I'm about to build a system which can cluster online news data based on the event they are related to. For examing if the result is correct, I need a large topic-labeled news dataset. And it seems nearly impossible for me to label them manually. So could anyone share some suggestions how can I get my hand on this type of dataset? Much appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[20 Newsgroups](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/) is a standard dataset to start with news clustering, classification, etc. You can use it for your experiments. From the description:

> The 20 Newsgroups data set is a collection of approximately 20,000 newsgroup documents, partitioned (nearly) evenly across 20 different newsgroups. To the best of my knowledge, it was originally collected by Ken Lang, probably for his Newsweeder: Learning to filter netnews paper, though he does not explicitly mention this collection. The 20 newsgroups collection has become a popular data set for experiments in text applications of machine learning techniques, such as text classification and text clustering.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've downloaded this dataset before. But the reason I can't use this dataset is that I need to apply event-based clustering, which requires the dataset must be prelabeled by the core event they're describing. If there's anyway I can achieve that form of news data that would be super helpful.